# Ajax Not Found (404) POST url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to submit a form using ajax to call the php file, but when I try to test it, the browser console prints the following error

[image]

Below is my ajax post code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent page refresh

        var email = $("#email").val();

        if (validateEmail(email)) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/send_form.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize form data
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("successfullySentForm").style.display = "block";
                },
                error: function() {
                    document.getElementById("genericError").style.display = "block";
                }
            });

        } else {

            document.getElementById("wrongEmailFormat").style.display = "block";

        }
    });
});
```

Im running this website in my webserver.

Comment: Error 404 means the server answers and tells that the file php/send_form.php does not exist. The problem is at your server level, so I doubt someone could help you without more information on the server.

Comment: Try to paste the POST url in the browser to check if you have the path right

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to solve path related problems.

Example: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/file';

Comment: is that considered as answer!!

Comment: Updated answer related to problem, I hope this will help.